# FFmpeg Make Errors with v4l2

Tags: ffmpeg, v4l2

I tried checking out ffmpeg to build it as follows:

1. git clone https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg.git ffmpeg
2. cd ffmpeg
3. `./configure --disable-asm --disable-v4l2-m2m --disable-indev=v4l2 --disable-outdev=v4l2`
4. make

But I get the following errors:

```
libavcodec/v4l2_m2m_enc.c: In function ‘v4l2_set_ext_ctrl’: 
libavcodec/v4l2_m2m_enc.c:51: warning: braces around scalar initializer 
libavcodec/v4l2_m2m_enc.c:51: warning: (near initialization for 
‘ctrls.count’) libavcodec/v4l2_m2m_enc.c:55: error: ‘struct v4l2_ext_controls’ has no member named ‘ctrl_class’ libavcodec/v4l2_m2m_enc.c:60: 
error: ‘struct v4l2_ext_control’ has no member named ‘value’ 
libavcodec/v4l2_m2m_enc.c: In function ‘v4l2_get_ext_ctrl’: 
libavcodec/v4l2_m2m_enc.c:71: warning: braces around scalar initializer 
libavcodec/v4l2_m2m_enc.c:71: warning: (near initialization for 
‘ctrls.count’) libavcodec/v4l2_m2m_enc.c:76: error: ‘struct v4l2_ext_controls’ has no member named ‘ctrl_class’ libavcodec/v4l2_m2m_enc.c:89: 
error: ‘struct v4l2_ext_control’ has no member named ‘value’ make: *** 
[libavcodec/v4l2_m2m_enc.o] Error 1
```

Any idea how to proceed ?

Comment: I have same problem with --disable-x86asm (instead of --disable-asm). Could this be a environmental issue ?

Comment: The configure step produces an output which still lists v4l2_m2m as an external library providing hardware acceleration

Comment: Is there a linux driver that needs updating ?

Comment: I added /usr/include in my path. That should ensure that /usr/include/linux/videodev2.h is found. Still that does not help

Comment: I do notice that in my /usr/include/linux/videodev2.h, the structure v4l2_ext_control is defined as:                                                                   
  struct v4l2_ext_control {
      __u32 id;
      __u32 size;
      __u32 reserved2[1];
      union {
           __s32 value;
           __s64 value64;
           char *string;
           __u8 *p_u8;
           __u16 *p_u16;
           __u32 *p_u32;
          void *ptr;
       };
   } __attribute__ ((packed));

Comment: Is this an old version of the videodev2.h header file ?

Comment: Did you find a solution?